# Does pushViewController retain the controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am struggling to find out if pushViewController retains the controller, currently I have the following code (which works) ...

```
ColorController *colorController = [[ColorController alloc] initWithNibName:nibColor bundle:nil];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:colorController animated:YES];
[colorController release];
```

but am considering removing the release and adding an autorelease ...

```
ColorController *colorController = [[[ColorController alloc] initWithNibName:nibColor bundle:nil] autorelease];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:colorController animated:YES];
```

Much appreciated

Gary

Comment: I'd use `release` here since you know you're done with `colorController` and `UINavigationController#pushViewController:animated` retains `colorController`. But, `autorelease` works too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This does nothing...

```
ColorController *colorController = [[ColorController alloc] initWithNibName:nibColor bundle:nil];
[[[self navigationController] pushViewController:colorController animated:YES] autorelease];
```

You are autoreleasing the return value of pushViewController:animated:, which is void.

Your first snippet is valid, and correct. pushViewController: does indeed retain the controller that is pushed.

Edit: In your updated code, there is little difference between the two samples. Both maintain proper retain counts. However, it is a "best practice" to avoid using autoRelease unless necessary (especially in a memory sensitive area, like the iPhone). This helps your application to maintain a more predictable and manageable memory footprint.

Comment: Thank you, sorry again for dropping the autorelease on the wrong line. Just what I was after.

Comment: Typos happen, just wanted to make sure it wasn't intentional! haha.

Comment: It's also a best practice to prefer autorelease to avoid coding errors. Which do you choose?

Well, if Instruments tells you that autorelease is taking up a significant amount of CPU or memory, then sure you can use explicit release calls. But this is very unlikely.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the view controller is retained.

There isn't a huge difference between the two code blocks you posted (at least the version I'm looking at -- other people probably saw an earlier version with a misplaced call to `autorelease`). You could use either one. It's a matter of style.

Comment: Thank you Shaggy Frog, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sure does.  Anytime you give one object to another SDK object like this, it will be retained.  Though that second line isn't autoreleasing what you think.  Usually you want the `autorelease` on the same line as the `init` for clarity sake.

```
ColorController *colorController = [[[ColorController alloc] initWithNibName:nibColor bundle:nil] autorelease];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:colorController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If want to try, you should try this

```
id temp = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:temp animated:YES];
```

you'll be navigated to any other previous ViewController that are available in the stack.